# How do I properly place each character in "in which country do you eat dinner?"

Tags: sentence-structure

I am trying to figure out how to write "In which country do you eat dinner?"

I know I need 你 (you), 哪 (which(which is my vocabulary word)), 个 (measure word), 国 (country), 吃 (eat), and 晚饭 (dinner).

I just don't know in what order I should put the sentence! For example, should I put 你 before 哪? Tell me if any of these two following sentences are correct:

1. 你吃晚饭哪个国吗?
2. 哪个国你吃晚饭？

Comment: What does the original sentence mean in English?

Comment: Dunno that the original sentence means .... +1

Comment: the modal particle （语气助词）吗 can be attached at 
the end of a 是非问句， i。e。 yes or no question，
therefore as in the answers below there should be no 吗 at the end， in case there is an interrogative pronoun （疑问的代词）like 哪， 呢 can be attached。

Comment: (I corrected the grammar bug in the question.)

Comment: Normally, a native Chinese speaker would say 国家 for “country”.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also not sure what the original english phrase means, but normal phrase order has the subject first , followed by time, place and then verb+adverb.

If your sentence is "IN which country you eat dinner?" the sentence should be 你在哪个国家吃晚饭？

Answer (score 0):

Which country do you eat dinner?

你去哪个国家吃晚饭？

Answer (score 0):

As a Chinese, I would translate this in to "你在哪个国家吃晚饭？".